# animate 2 points of a shape to follow the mouse on mouse hover

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, raphael

I've got a simple shape in vector and I would like to animate just the 2 top point of the shape to follow horizontally the mouse movement on hover.
I would like to post it on my website with html5 canvas.
Could someone help me understanding how this can be done (possibly easily)?
Thank you!

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple process:

1. Listen for `mousemove` events on your canvas.
2. Clear the canvas and redraw your image x-aligned with the mouse position.

Here's an example that let's you horizontally drag Pikachu by the left ear on a canvas element:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var imgLeft=3;
var imgTop=100;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/pikachu.png";
function start(){
  draw(0);
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
}

function draw(x){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(img,x-imgLeft,imgTop);
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);

  draw(mouseX);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move the mouse to move Pikachu by the ear</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```